# Slack API CORS error with axios in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, slack-api

I'm building an app with Capacitor JS & Nuxt JS to interface with the Slack API so that I can set my Slack status, I've created a Slack App and have a `xoxp-` token which works just fine when I hit the endpoint with a `POST` request via Postman, but from my browser (localhost) and from the running app on my phone I'm getting the following CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://slack.com/api/users.profile.set' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Now this seems silly because you **must** use the `authorization` header to provide the Bearer token for authentication, but even after temporarily omitting this, the CORS error remains.

I'm trying to `POST` to the endpoint for [users.profile.set
View another method](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set#args)

What am I missing in my Axios code?

```js
setSlackStatusWithReminder (title, expiry) {
  const body = this.convertToQueryString({
    profile: this.convertToQueryString(this.profile),
    token: 'xoxp-mytoken'
  })

  this.$axios.post('https://slack.com/api/users.profile.set', body, {
    timeout: 10000,
    transformRequest(data, headers) {
      delete headers.common['Content-Type'];
      return data;
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res)

    if (res.data.ok != true) {
      alert('something went wrong with the .then')
    }

    this.isSettingStatus = false
    this.actions.isShown = false
  }).catch(err => {
    this.isSettingStatus = false
    this.actions.isShown = false
  })
},
```

#### UPDATE

I've got a function to convert my request body into a query string from my data, which looks like:

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      profile: {
        status_text: '',
        status_emoji: '',
        status_expiration: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query string function to convert body

```js
convertToQueryString (obj) {
  const convert = Object.keys(obj)
                         .map((key, index) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[key])}`)
                         .join('&')

  return convert
},
```

And I'm building it up like:

```js
const body = this.convertToQueryString({
        profile: this.convertToQueryString(this.profile),
        token: 'xoxp-mytoken'
      })
```

It's giving me an `invalid_profile` response.

Comment: I really don't think slack-api is intended to be accessed from browser) Maybe there are some cors options in api settings but I doubt that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this was so difficult, the following is a valid `POST` request to the Slack API:

```js
// this.profile -> is the object with the status_* fields
const body = `profile=${JSON.stringify(this.profile)}&token=some_token`

this.$axios.post('https://slack.com/api/users.profile.set', body, {
  timeout: 10000,
  transformRequest(data, headers) {
    delete headers.common['Content-Type'];
    return data;
  }
}).then(res => {
  console.log(err)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Slack doesn't respond to the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request with a compatible response.

Avoid the preflight check entirely by ensuring it matches the requirements to be handled as a so-called ["simple request"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests).

Notably, ensure the content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, serialize the request body to match and do not use the `Authorization` header to pass your bearer token, instead pass it as an [argument in your request](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set#arg_token) (`token`).

Comment: So how would I put my code above into practive, I've just tried setting the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and can't see where-else to pass the token since the docs doesn't have an example in JS here

Comment: The docs says to transmit the token in the [header](https://api.slack.com/web#slack-web-api__basics__post-bodies__json-encoded-bodies)

Comment: @RyanH ["However, you may also pass tokens in all Web API calls as a POST body parameter called token."](https://api.slack.com/web#authentication)

Comment: Okay, so after sending the token as a `token` param in the body, I get a `Content-Type` CORS error telling me I'm not allowed this, so I delete that with: `transformRequest(data, headers) { delete headers.common['Content-Type']; return data; }` and I get a response telling me that my data is in an invalid format, because it's now missing a content type, I tried `JSON.stringify()` for my `body` too.

Comment: @RyanH as I mentioned in my answer, you need to url-encode the request body. [Here is an example of that from the axios docs.](https://axios-http.com/docs/urlencoded)

Comment: That helps further, I've created a function to encode my body but get an `invalid_profile` response now, I've updated my description with related code - this is by far one of the worst APIs I've used so far

Comment: Also trying to figure out how this will work for a `GET` request to get a profile since I can't encode the token https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.get